# How do I make elements sway back and forth in a loop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, animation, adobe-after-effects, adobe-premiere

I have an illustration and I want some of its elements to subtly sway back and forth or slowly scroll across the screen (clouds). You can see what I mean in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kpO-nyGEBJ4

I also want to throw in some frame-by-frame animation. I currently do all my illustration work in Photoshop so I'm pretty good with the program. I know I can do the frame-by-frame stuff using Photoshop's Timeline but I don't know if Photoshop can handle the other elements swaying back and forth.

My file consists of every element on separate layers so I'm ready to go, just not sure where to start.

How would I go about doing this and what program(s) is ideal?

Comment: Video editing is generally off-topic here.  Photoshop only has quite basic video editing capabilities, and so probably not the right software.  For more complex video you probably need something like AfterEffects, and if so probably best to post your question on Video Production Stack Exchange instead.

Answer (score 0):

There have been at least 15 years available numerous video editors which can do it. After Effects is a complex one for serious pros and hobbyists. Many simpler multitrack video editors are available with this capability. Only the most elementary ones either have too few tracks or there's available no animated transformations.

You can place different moving elements to different video tracks which are layered to the wanted front-back order. Static single image items can move if you insert 2 differently moved, rotated and scaled versions of the same item and define the transformation must be animated.

The moving sky needs transparent hole in the foreground image. Complex editors allow masks, in simpler ones you must use key colors (=certain color is defined to be rendered as transparent) or have the foreground as PNG or TIF which has prepared transparent area. As well the sky can be in the front, only mask it.

In video editing terminology you can find general term "picture in picture" for inserting layered items to the video image.

Actually you stretch the inserted image in video timeline to as long video clip as needed . Then you add transformation effect (=move, rotate, scale +warp in advanced editing programs) to that clip. You set only the first and last transformations as keyframes. The editor interpolates smooth intermediate frames automatically.

Moving back can be the same clip as copied and reversed (=2 mouse drags) or the transformation only is edited to have also the return.

Repeating loop = several copies of the same clip.

Complex movements can be got by inserting more keyframes and velocity curves.

Elastic looking swaying needs also a kind of warp transform to make the object to bend nicely. That transform is not available in simple video editors. But there are numerous image warping tools which output the result as video sequence. If you can use After Effects check this guide https://www.videocaddy.com/articles/puppet-warp-tool.php

Making the forth and back movement to look smooth and elastic is the most difficult part of your problem. The problem grows really big when one wants to present movements of humans or animals. One solution is to use physics simulation where the bodies have kinematic models. Another solution is to study video sequences which contain recorded movements of real humans and animals.There are tools which put drawn characters to follow movements of real actors when the movements are recorded withe special tools and the actors have trackable clothing.